# Isset wont recognize the submit on POST PHP

Tags: php, forms, post, isset

`if (isset($_POST['submit']))` in the following code wont execute, same goes for the `if(isset($_POST['Q1']))`

```
<form action='' onsubmit="return validateQuiz()" method="post">
            <section>
                <p>Who cares?</p>
                <input type="radio" name="Q1" value="Q1_1">
                <label for="Q1_1">Me?</label><br>
                <input type="radio" name="Q1" value="Q1_2">
                <label for="Q1_2">No one</label><br>
                <input type="radio" name="Q1" value="Q1_3">
                <label for="Q1_3">That guy</label>
            </section>

            <br>
            <input id="submit" type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
        </form>
```

In the same file there goes a php block right under this form that goes:

```
<?php

        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            if(isset($_POST['Q1']))
            {
                echo "You have selected :" . $_POST['Q1'];  //  Displaying selected value not working
            }
        }
        ?>
```

For further information, I've tried doing pure `if (isset($_POST['submit']))` to see what the real problem was, and it doesn't even set the isset to true even tho the form was submitteed. I've also tried the GET method instead of POST, still doesnt work. Pure echo-code without anything else works so php is working as intended.

Here is a picture of how it looks if anyone is wondering and such, Right under submit should appear text of what was selected.
[image: picture of the current website]

Comment: `$_POST['submit']` is not a value in your form.

Comment: I realized that name is an important part of the post checker, Ive added a name value for the submit button but it still doesnt work?

Comment: `var_dump($_POST)` gives what?

Comment: Tried this, got nothing as an output @user3783243

Comment: When you say "nothing" do you mean **nothing** or do you mean `array(0) { }`?

Comment: as in array(0) { }, I did 'echo var_dump($_POST);' for your information

Comment: So you aren't sending a POST. Does `validateQuiz` do form processing?

Comment: Then the most likely explanation is that the function `validateQuiz` is doing something to break it.  Remove `onsubmit="return validateQuiz()"`.

Comment: Ah yup, it was the problem, thanks for helping @Quentin & user3783243